# Is there a way to move NSTextView 's indicator around?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, nstextview

This is about Cocoa (OSX) TextViews

You know that blinking line which hints the position where the next character will be inserted? How to move that inside programmatically? I just want to animate typing.

I read about

```
- (void)insertText:(id)aString
  replacementRange:(NSRange)replacementRange
```

Is there a way I could use that to simulate the above?

Otherwise, Can I simulate the back arrow key? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

```
textView.setSelectedRange(NSRange(location: 5,length: 0))
```